# .htaccess single line gives server error 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess

within the .htaccess file's I have a mod_deflate section. Within it, the line: **Header append Vary User-Agent** is the cause for a server error 500. When I remove this line, just this line it works well. Has anyone ever encountered something like this? I'm running `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS` and `Apache 2.4.18`

```
IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/js
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Comment: check in "Loaded Modules" if mod_deflate is disable or not installed 
using phpinfo();

Comment: `Header append Vary User-Agent` worked for me

Comment: @GaneshKandu mod_deflate doesn't even appear in phpinfo()

Comment: you don't have installed or enabled mod_deflate ask to your web host to enable it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. That was totally my bad. It seemed that the:

```
Header append Vary User-Agent
```

was causing the 500 server error issue because the `header-load` module was simply not loaded. adding it to the `mods-enabled` as a symlink and restarting apache resolved the issue.